# be friendly very long meaning

Tags: meaning

> I have a lot of friends. But they wouldn't be friendly very long if I
>   were do something.

What does be friendly very long mean here?

Comment: Are you sure this is a grammatical sentence?

Comment: @M.A.Ramezani It's from the godfather movie.

Comment: I'm afraid the edits you made to the quote not only changed the meaning but made it ungrammatical as well.

Answer (score 1):

It's talking about time:

> I have a lot of friends. But they wouldn't be friendly (for a) very long
>   (time) if I were to (be rude about them behind their backs).
>
> There is someone who I don't get on with at work, but he wouldn't be
>   hostile very long if I involved him in my project.